# Flutter & Firestore - How to create a distinct list of documents when using multiple queries?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Since firebase / firestore does not support distinct in queries, I'm looking for a way to create a distinct list on the client. The reason for this is that in my particular situation I must have multiple DB queries and this can sometimes result in two or more documents being returned that have the same values (ie the same document).

I have tried creating a Set like so

```
final set = Set<User>.from(_people.map<User>((user) => user));
final distinctList = set.map((user) => user).toList();
/// doesn't work since any duplicate document is a separate instance...
```

However the Set class, as explained in the Flutter docs, only sees an object as distinct if it is indeed the same **instance** (as opposed to having the exact same values, which is what I'm looking for).

How would one go about doing this in a straightforward way that doesn't consume tons of resources, such as creating a separate list and iterating over the whole thing to compare fields for each entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this would be to use the [equatable package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) in conjunction with your User class. In your class:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class User {
  final String uid;
  final String photoURL;
  final String email;
  final String displayName;

  User({
    this.uid,
    this.photoURL,
    this.email,
    this.displayName,

    /// the important part.
    /// make sure to include all your properties above that you want to check for equality.
    @override
    List<Object> get props => [
      uid,
      photoURL,
      email,
      displayName,
  ];
}
```

This effectively overrides the built in dart equality checking for the same instance for the User class. Now the Set class will see two User documents from firebase / firestore as equal, and the resulting set will only include each User document once.

```
final set = Set<User>.from(_people.map<User>((user) => user));
final distinctList = set.map((user) => user).toList();
/// list is now only distinct user documents.
```